# How to boot Legacy Ruby on Rails 1.2.5 app on Rack (to support Passenger)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, passenger

Is there a way to run Legacy Ruby on Rails version 1.2.5 app on Rack in order to support Phusion Passenger hosting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question doesn't make any sense. Phusion Passenger supports both "legacy" Rails apps (those that are not Rack compliant, i.e. Rails < 2.2) **as well as** Rack-compliant apps.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it causes problems. Had to upgrade my app.

Comment: If you posted details about your problem maybe people can actually help you. When asking for help on the Internet, don't be vague. People can't read your mind.